# JQuery checkbox manipulation not working after initial click

Tags: checkbox

I have a table of checkboxes. At the top is an Administrator box, then below a bunch of other permissions. If the Admin box is checked all other boxes should be checked, and if another box is unchecked then the Admin box should uncheck. I have it working on the initial click but if you click the Admin box it checks all others, then uncheck an other option it unchecks the Admin. Check the Admin a second time and nothing happens.

http://jsfiddle.net/HCpQg/1/

```
$("#administrator").click(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.permissions').attr('checked',true);
}
});

$(".permissions").click(function(){
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
} else {
$('#administrator').attr('checked',false);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .prop() as opposed to .attr().

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents: if you use uniform styling:

```
$(function () {
    $(":checkbox").uniform();
});
```

then you will need to call

```
$.uniform.update();
```

after you dynamically check/uncheck checkbox. I've just spent 6 hours trying until I dug up this bit...